# warning: "adjust the group aesthetic" while visualizing clusters with R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created two clusters while I used the code to visualize the clusters through line chart, it shows "Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

**Code**

```
ggplot(b,aes(A, avg, colour=cluster))+geom_line()
```

**Dataset**

> A  cluster  avg
>
> A1  1         0.2
>
> A1  2         0.3
>
> A2  1         0.3
>
> A2  2         0.4

Comment: You don't have `location` column and `cluster` should be `Cluster`

Answer (score 1):

```
b <- data.frame(A=c("A1","A2","A3"),
    cluster=c(1,2,1),
    avg=c(0.2,0.3,0.3))
x11()
ggplot(b,aes(A, avg, colour=cluster))+geom_point()
```

You only have one point so don't use lines, group aesthetics is explained here http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html